# What factors do you use to evaluate the quality of a website template?

Tags: template

**Examples of website templates being:**

- [templatemonster.com](http://templatemonster.com)
- [websitetemplates.com](http://websitetemplates.com)
- [buytemplates.net](http://buytemplates.net)
- [designload.net](http://designload.net)
- [templaterover.com](http://templaterover.com)
- [boxedart.com](http://boxedart.com)
- [pixelmill.com](http://pixelmill.com)
- [templateworld.com](http://templateworld.com)
- [themeforest.net](http://themeforest.net)

**(If there's a popular source I'm missing, please comment. Thanks!)**

Comment: http://themeforest.net/ is another one you might add to the list.

Comment: **@themeforest.net:** Thanks, just add themeforest.net to the list!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't bought templates before, but if I were to buy a template, I'd do something like the following process:

- Figure out my site's objectives.
- Research my target market.
- Look at other sites in the same
  industry/niche.
- Weed out templates that have been
  used too many times, especially any
  used by competition.
- Choose the 2-3 templates that will
  best be able to accomplish the site's
  objectives while appealing to the
  target market. Depending on your
  strategy and/or niche, you may or may
  not want it to be like other sites in
  the same niche.
- Do a quick test by showing people in
  my target market which template
  appeals to them, which would be
  easiest to use, which would entice
  them to fulfill the objectives while
  they're on the site, and so on...Have
  them rate each question for each
  template on a scale of 1-5 and then
  add up your points. You shouldn't
  need more than 4-5 people.
- Try to buy a exclusive rights for the
  template so it can't be resold from
  that point forward.
- If I find some templates I like, but
  nothing quite suits the site, I'd
  contact template authors that I feel
  could do a good job based on their
  other work and ask them to create a
  custom template.

Comment: **@Virtuosi_Media:** Nice answer, thanks! -- Question, how would you contact, or find contact info for the template authors? Most the time it's just a username as far as I'm able to tell.

Comment: If you're going to buy exclusive rights for a template anyway, I highly advise you to just hire a professional designer or full-service web development firm to create a custom design for you. It'll be cheaper and of higher quality. $2700+ for the kind of designs on those sites is a complete rip-off. You can get a full site with a far superior design for less than that (shop for a good designer who builds sites using an open source CMS).

Comment: @Lèse majesté - That's a very good point. @blunders - It might not be possible to contact the author in every case. You could try Googling the username or contacting the template site to see if they could put you in contact with the author.

Comment: **@Lèse majesté:** Agree, find it hard to believe someone would pay more that $100 for a stock template. In fact, I've never bought one, but have used free templates for OS-CMS systems, and was very happy with the results after I updated them for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

I choose my three or four favourite, and show them to people:

1. Whose opinion I respect
2. Who know about the business/product the website is for
3. Who are not scared to tell me that all my choices suck

Mainly because after you've spent hour after hour staring at a million generic templates, it's easy to get lost and lose sight of the bigger picture. Also, if you spent 2 hours staring a sucky templates, the one that seems the least sucky tends to register as really good in your mind, when in fact it's still pretty sucky.

Comment: **@Farseeker:** Agree. It's really hard to know how people will really react, but at the same rate how they react is influenced by the request for a reaction... :-) ...oh, well.